# Update a fillable pdf using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm having trouble updating named fields in a fillable pdf.
My code is as shown:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

reader = PdfFileReader("invoice_template.pdf")
page = reader.getPage(0)

data_dict = {
    "business_name_1": "Consulting",
    "customer_name": "company.io",
    "customer_email": "example@icloud.com",
}

writer = PdfFileWriter()
writer.updatePageFormFieldValues(page, fields=data_dict)
writer.addPage(page)

with open("newfile.pdf", "wb") as fh:
    writer.write(fh)
```

I have checked the fields dictionary using `myfile.getFormTextFields()` before and after calling `updatePageFormFieldValues()` and they do get updated. However the generated pdf has none of the field values in it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The pdf I'm using can be found [here](https://bostata.com/download/post/fillable_pdf/invoice_template.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is fixed by setting the `NeedAppearances` value of the PDF to `True`. This can be done by a function:

```
def set_need_appearances_writer(writer: PdfFileWriter):
    # See 12.7.2 and 7.7.2 for more information: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf
    try:
        catalog = writer._root_object
        # get the AcroForm tree
        if "/AcroForm" not in catalog:
            writer._root_object.update({
                NameObject("/AcroForm"): IndirectObject(len(writer._objects), 0, writer)
            })

        need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
        writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)
        # del writer._root_object["/AcroForm"]['NeedAppearances']
        return writer

    except Exception as e:
        print('set_need_appearances_writer() catch : ', repr(e))
        return writer
```

Then, you can just add the line `set_need_appearances_writer(writer)` after the line `writer = PdfFileWriter()` and the form should be updated!

You can view more information here: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/355

**Fixed code**

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from PyPDF2.generic import BooleanObject, NameObject, IndirectObject

def set_need_appearances_writer(writer: PdfFileWriter):
    # See 12.7.2 and 7.7.2 for more information: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf
    try:
        catalog = writer._root_object
        # get the AcroForm tree
        if "/AcroForm" not in catalog:
            writer._root_object.update({
                NameObject("/AcroForm"): IndirectObject(len(writer._objects), 0, writer)
            })

        need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
        writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)
        # del writer._root_object["/AcroForm"]['NeedAppearances']
        return writer

    except Exception as e:
        print('set_need_appearances_writer() catch : ', repr(e))
        return writer

myfile = PdfFileReader("invoice_template.pdf")
first_page = myfile.getPage(0)

writer = PdfFileWriter()
set_need_appearances_writer(writer)

data_dict = {
            'business_name_1': 'Consulting',
            'customer_name': 'company.io',
            'customer_email': 'example@icloud.com'
            }

writer.updatePageFormFieldValues(first_page, fields=data_dict)
writer.addPage(first_page)

with open("newfile.pdf","wb") as new:
    writer.write(new)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I definitely wouldnt have solved  this anytime soon. I was getting an error and added the imports `from PyPDF2.generic import BooleanObject, NameObject, IndirectObject` after following the thread you linked.